# Express any odd number greater than 5 as the sum of 3 primes

Tags: java, primes, number-theory, goldbach-conjecture

For a given **odd number** `n` I want to efficiently compute `3` primes whose sum is equal to `n`. If there are multiple solutions then I want the one with the smallest primes (I want `2+2+17=21` instead of `3+5+13=21`)

This is [always possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture) for`n>5`.

My current approach is to reduce the problem to computing `2` primes whose sum is equal to `n-3` and then I simply output the `2` computed primes and `3` since they obviously sum up to `n`. I choose `3` since it is the smallest odd prime and when I subtract it from `n` I get an even number, therefore it should be part of every solution I'm looking for. I'm using [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/Goldbach.java.html) to compute the sum of `2` primes, it works if n is even which it is in my case (since I subtracted `3` from an odd `n`).

My approach doesn't work since there are solutions without a `3` as a summand (`41=2+2+37`).

Is there a straightforward approach which I'm missing?

Comment: there is a chance this might belong on mathematics, not sure

Comment: @1blustone I encountered this during an online programming contest, there is some elementary number theory involved. The final solution should obviously be a program (preferably java) which solves the problem.

Comment: "I want 2+2+3=7 instead of 2+5=7" Why would you choose "2+5" if it doesn't even use 3 primes?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis my bad, edited it.

Comment: I didn't get why `2+2+17` is smaller than `3+5+13`.

Comment: @talex because the first only has 2 and 17, but the second has 3, 5 and 13. So, there's one less prime in the first, so it's smaller. QED.

Comment: @talex the goal is to output the "first 3 primes which sum up to n" as I would call it. I want to minimize the first summand, minimize the second summand and then minimize the third summand. I edited the post to clarify that. Since 2<3 I choose 2+2+17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test whether n-4 is prime.  If so, your answer is {2, 2, n-4}.  Otherwise, your original approach will work.  You'll never use just one 2 because your sum would be even.

Comment: Nice observation, now my approach is complete.

Comment: Is there really always either two 2s or a 3 in the three primes? Amazing.